# How do I redirect to another webpage using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

hello i am trying to redirect to another webapage but its not working:

code which written to redirect:

```
  window.location.replace = "/goal/viewgoal/goalID";
```

html code:

```
   <button id="submit-new-goal"class="btn btn-sm btn-primary m-l-md redirect">
     Continue Save
   </button>
```

complete code:

```
  if (!checkValidation) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/goal/createGoal",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      goalSchemaObj,
      userID,
      selectedTeachers
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("created Goal", data);
      $.bootstrapGrowl("<h4>Success!</h4><p>Goal Created.</p>", {
        type: "success",
        delay: 4500,
        allow_dismiss: true
      });
       window.location.replace = "/goal/viewgoal/goalID";
    },
    error: async err => {
      const response = await err;
      console.log("creation-cehck", response);
      $.bootstrapGrowl("<h4>Error!</h4><p>something wrong.</p>", {
        type: "danger",
        delay: 4500,
        allow_dismiss: true
      });
    }
  });
} else {
  $.bootstrapGrowl("<h4>warning!</h4><p>Please Fill all the fields.</p>", {
    type: "warning",
    delay: 4500,
    allow_dismiss: true
  });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)

Comment: @PatrickEvans   data is saving into db and also alert show data saved but its not redirecting to another page

Comment: @Gandalfion  i use window.location.replace by seeing it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/503093/125981 this seems like a duplicate

Comment: window.location.href = "/goal/viewgoal/goalID"

Answer (score 0):

use

```
window.location.replace('url');
```

instead

```
window.location.replace='url';
```

Comment: I see you attempted to edit the question to make it look like a closed as duplicate - that is not how this works, by voting to close that automatically adds that  "edit" to the question when enough people vote that way.

Comment: now its using this id "http://localhost:3000/goal/viewgoal/goalID" not saving it inti db